# Solving FizzBuzz with Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, fizzbuzz

I am trying to solve FizzBuzz using Keras and it works quite well for numbers between 1 and 10.000 (90-100% win rate and close to 0 loss). However, if I try even higher numbers, that is numbers between 1 and 100.000 it doesn't seem to perform well (~50% win rate, loss ~0.3). In fact, it performs quite poorly and I have no clue what I can do to solve this task. So far I am using a very simple neural net architecture with 3 hidden layers:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(2000, input_dim=state_size, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(1000, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(500, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(num_actions, activation="softmax"))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=["accuracy"])
```

I found that the more neurons I have the better it performs, at least for numbers below 10.000.

I am training my neural net in a step-wise fashion, meaning that I am not computing the inputs and targets beforehand, but instead train the network step by step. Again, this works quite well and it shouldn't make a difference right? Here's the main loop:

```
for epoch in range(np_epochs):
    action = random_number()
    x_raw = to_binary(action)
    x = np.expand_dims(x_raw, 0)
    prediction = model.predict(x)

    y, victory, _, _ = check_prediction(action, prediction)

    memory.append((x_raw, y))

    curr_batch_size = min(batch_size, len(memory))

    batch = random.sample(memory, curr_batch_size)

    inputs = []
    targets = []

    for i, t in batch:
      inputs.append(i)
      targets.append(t)

    if victory:
      wins += 1

    loss, accuracy = model.train_on_batch(np.array(inputs), np.array(targets))
```

As you can see, I am training my network not on decimal numbers but convert them into binary first before feeding it into the net.

Another thing to mention here is that I am using a memory, to make it more like a supervised problem. I thought it may perform better if train on numbers that the neural net has already been trained on. It doesn't seem to make any difference at all.

Is there anything I can do to solve this particular problem with a neural net? I mean is it so hard for a function approximator to figure out the simple math behind FizzBuzz? Am I doing something wrong? Do you suggest a different architecture?

See my code on [MachineLabs](https://machinelabs.ai/editor/Bkh-yeOEz/1516047963145-SkmvCK5EG?tab=console&file=main.py). You can simply fork my lab and fiddle with it if you want. To view to code, simply click on the 'Editor' tab at the top.